# Is it possible to use GAE locally?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, openid

I need to make my GWT application be an OpenID consumer and it looks like GAE has an existing solution for this. Is it possible to use GAE in case I'm not going to host my app at appspot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/) could do the job.

> AppScale is an open-source hybrid cloud platform. AppScale implements a number of popular APIs including those of Google App Engine, MapReduce (via Hadoop), MPI and others.